# AppScript for Google Sheets Refuses to Run

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-oauth

I'm not sure why it won't, since I've already addressed the oAuthScope issues for it, but for some reason this code refuses to run.

Here's my appsscript.json file:

```json
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp"
  ],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "sheets": {
    "macros": [{
      "menuName": "writeStudents",
      "functionName": "writeStudents"
    }]
  }
}
```

Here's the code that doesn't run:

```js
function writeStudents() {
  var activeFolder = DA.getFolderById(getActiveFolder_());
  var studentItr = activeFolder.getFiles();
  var rows = SS.getRange(ActiveStudents_).getValues();
  rows = rows.map(x => x = ['', '']);
  var idx = 0;
  while (studentItr.hasNext()) {
    var student = studentItr.next();

    rows[idx++] = [student.getName(), student.getId()];
  }
  SS.getRange(ActiveStudents_).setValues(rows);
}


function getActiveFolder_() {
  var year = new Date().getFullYear();
  var folder = SS.getRange(ActiveStudentsFolders_).getValues()
    .filter(row => row[0] == year);
  return folder[0][1];
}
```

I have this particular code in a trigger that's supposed to run upon opening the file, and the only error I get is that I don't have the right permissions, and gives me the link to add to my appscript.json file:

> Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFolderById. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive)
>
> at writeStudents_(Overview:2:25)
> at writeStudents(Public:26:3)
> at onOpen(Events:3:3)

You'll definitely find those auths inside the json file.

Now to explain a couple of things:

The `DA` and `SS` are `DriveApp` and `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` respectively, that I've turned into alias variables so that I can use them with shorter names.

`ActiveStudents_` and `ActiveStudents_` are also variables for the named ranges I'm using inside the script. These are also correct, since, at one point before this one, I managed to get this code to work.

As for the error call stack: I made a file for testing all of the functions, spread across several script files, in one place, by making public wrapper functions of all the functions I wanted to eventually be public. That part *does* work. However, when I found that *this* function did not, I used the original function, publicized it, and tested it from its original file. All it does is spin forever, and doesn't even make it to the first line in the function, even when adding a break point.

To make matters worse, I can't even get a basic console log to work. I just tried this:

```js
function test() {
  console.log('Are you working at all?!');
}
```

It just hangs there, not doing anything.

What's going on here?

Comment: `onOpen(Events:3:3)`. `onOpen` is a simple trigger. Just in case, you didn't understand the duplicate.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible.